# Java BufferedImage "Chunk" blurring Issue

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm currently trying to create a simple (step-based) level generation algorithm. So far, it is producing a product I am happy with, however for some reason the image's pixels are being changed to a bunch of different grey colors even though my code only allows for two colors (black and white). The especially strange part is that the pixel alterations are only happening in chunks around the image itself.

Any ideas on how to go about getting rid of this strange "blurring" effect?

The Image Generation code:

```
package com.ryan.game.level;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomLevelGenerator
{
    public BufferedImage generateLevel(int maxTiles)
    {
        BufferedImage levelImage = new BufferedImage(128, 128, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        Color customColor = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        int myColor = customColor.getRGB();
        int xPos = 64;
        int yPos = 64;

        for(int i = maxTiles; i > 0; i--)
        {
            levelImage.setRGB(xPos, yPos, myColor); //Sets current pos to white (Floor tile)

            while(true)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();

                //=== One is up, Two is Right, Three is Down, Four is Left ===//
                int direction = rand.nextInt(4) + 1; //Generates number 1-4

                if (direction == 1 && yPos != 1) //Going up
                {
                    yPos -= 1;
                    break;
                }
                if (direction == 2 && xPos != 127) //Going right
                {
                    xPos += 1;
                    break;
                }
                if (direction == 3 && yPos != 127) //Going down
                {
                    yPos += 1;
                    break;
                }
                if (direction == 4 && xPos != 1) //Going left
                {
                    xPos -= 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        File f = new File("imageTest.jpg");
        try
        {
            ImageIO.write(levelImage, "jpg", f);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return levelImage;
    }
}
```

The Image Produced (Image will change each time code is run, but always has this effect on it): **ZOOM INTO PICTURE TO SEE AS IT IS SMALL**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing the image as a JPEG, which is a lossy format. In particular, JPEG isn't very good at representing step changes in intensity - you get so-called "ringing" artefacts in the image.

This is because JPEG uses the discrete cosine transform to represent the images - i.e. the image is the weighted sum of smoothly-varying functions. This is normally acceptable (or, at least, not noticeable) when you use a JPEG for natural photographs, since most of the image has smoothly-varying intensity.

Change the output format to a lossless one; try PNG.